# Are retracted Close votes retained in the user's review history and in the queue history?

Tags: support, review, retracted-close-votes

Is it correct that:

- users' public review history shows all close votes (cast in the Close review queue) including those that were retracted?
- Displayed histories of the various close reviews on a question retain all the close votes, including the withdrawn ones?   For example, it is possible that only one reviewer votes, to close, and then withdraws the vote; does the record of that queue remain unchanged?

Some of this can be answered by experimentation, but I did not want to potentially be recorded as a close voter on questions I did not mean to close, or to withdraw a close vote on things I did want to close.

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both. Voting to close a question in the Close Votes review queue does two things: cast a close vote, and mark your decision for the review item as 'Close'. You can retract the close vote, but not reverse the decision.